# How do I manage common lisp dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp, asdf

What's the lisp equivalent of a pip requirement file, ruby gemfile, node package.json, etc? I'm not entirely sure how asdf and quicklisp relate if those are the proper things to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A .asd file is a requirements file. Use quicklisp to install requirements.

Use ASDF to define a "system". Create a `my-system.asd` file.

```
(asdf:defsystem #:my-system
  :serial t
  :description "Describe my-system here"
  :author "My Name <my.name@example.com>"
  :license "Specify license here"
  :depends-on (#:hunchentoot
               #:cl-who)
  :components ((:file "package")
               (:file "dispatch")))
```

This creates the system named #:my-system. I'm not actually sure what the # denotes as I've seen system definitions without it in source code. Only the first line is required. `:depends-on` tells ASDF to load other systems before this new system definition is processed. In this case it loads `#:hunchentoot` and `#:cl-who`. `:components` load specific files. `package.lisp` and `dispatch.lisp` are loaded. `:serial t` tells it to load it in order. This is important if say `dispatch.lisp` depends on something in `package.lisp` such that `package.lisp` needs to be loaded first.

Use quicklisp to download and install the dependencies in `:depends-on`. Run
`(ql:quickload "my-system")`.

I haven't seen any sign of versioning.

Comment: `#:` stands for uninterned symbols (it's not obligatory). As for versioning, there's an appropriate `:version` field in `defsystem`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, pip's `requirements.txt` is very different from rubygem or node's `package.json`: the former specifies just the dependencies, while the latter ones describe the package, including its dependencies.

Python's `pip` actually also relies on the similar package description format which is called "eggs".

A pretty much direct equivalent of a rubygem is [ASDF](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/) `defsystem` form, usually placed in a file `<system-name>.asd` ("system" is the Lisp's term for what may be called package, module or library in other languages - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112797/proper-way-of-defining-packages-using-asdfdefsystem-and-quickproject/10113381#10113381) for a more detailed explanation).

The two major differences are:

- ASDF also allows to specify how to build (and also load, test etc) the system (somewhat equivalent to a makefile) — AFAIK, there's no such notion in rubygems or node whatsoever
- Unlike gems or node, ASDF doesn't provide a mechanism to download and install the package. This is where `quicklisp` comes in — it deals with fetching ASDF systems. But `ql` is not the only way here: historically there were other approaches for installing ASDF libraries, including `ASDF-Install` and `clbuild`, and others may come up in the future

Answer (score 2):

#### Qlot

For the relation with ASDF and Quicklisp the other answers give a nice approach.

I want to remark that now you can use a common lisp library quite similar to the ones pointed, that is available at quicklisp an is [Qlot](https://github.com/fukamachi/qlot). It is used to specify project-local dependencies. It is pretty similar to bundle and gemfile in ruby.

#### Quicklisp bundles

Also introduced in [2015-04-28](http://blog.quicklisp.org/2015/04/new-feature-quicklisp-library-bundles.html) you can use [quicklisp bundles](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/bundles.html) Quicklisp library bundles are self-contained sets of systems that are exported from Quicklisp and loadable without involving Quicklisp.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-to-one equivalent to those mentioned above. However, ASDF + Quicklisp combination comes pretty close.

With ASDF you define your systems (modules if you will) -- packaging your lisp files in a coherent way, and you declare your dependencies. Quicklisp is an online repository of sources for these systems. When you load a system with Quicklisp, it will download these dependencies and load them for you.

Now I'm not sure if there is such thing as versioning..

Comment: Re' versioning: you can define version in `defsystem`. Quicklisp isn't a repository it downloads things from many different sources, mostly Clicky, but there are some more. The ASD serves practically the same purpose as setup.py (the traditional way of creating Python packages).

Comment: @wvxvw What I mean with versioning is to declare it in your dependency (like a gemfile or package.json).. can you do that? And will Quicklisp then download the right version?

Edit: You're right that Quicklisp downloads from many sources and is not a repository -- updated answer